# [BT][HID] How is a Bluetooth HID connection handled in Ubuntu or android

Tags: android, bluetooth, hid

I am working on a project that uses the Bluetooth HID profile. I understand that the BlueZ stack in android has the HID support but its not extended to app layer by Android Framework.

My main concern is to understand the driver level flow for a Bluetooth HID device.
I would like to add a new HID device driver that can handle the key events from bluetooth HID device and pass it on to the Input subsystem.

Any help would be appriciated!!

thanks

Answer (score 1):

To understand the "level flow" you should start reading the specs, available on bluetooth.com and here: http://www.dawidurbanski.pl/public/download/projekty/bluepad/HID_SPEC_V10.pdf

You can also have a look at Teksoft Blueinput, as this application is a Bluetooth HID implementation. It currently supports keyboards and mouses, but has it's own Report Descriptor parser, so other devices could be easily added.